# returning query where field is null

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to use the following query with my table:

```
SELECT ARTICLE_NO, USERNAME, ACCESSSTARTS, ARTICLE_NAME, date_format(str_to_date(ACCESSSTARTS, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s'), '%d %m %Y' ) AS shortDate FROM AUCTIONS WHERE upper(ARTICLE_NAME) LIKE '%hardy%' and subcat = 'null' ORDER BY str_to_date(ACCESSSTARTS, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s'), article_no limit 0, 10
```

This should return over 100 records. subcat is null by default. Have I marked null incorrectly, or is there a different way to return records where a column is null?

Comment: spell error in question header, "retruning" instead "returning"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should look like this:

```
SELECT ARTICLE_NO, USERNAME, ACCESSSTARTS, ARTICLE_NAME, date_format(str_to_date(ACCESSSTARTS, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s'), '%d %m %Y' ) AS shortDate 
FROM AUCTIONS
WHERE upper(ARTICLE_NAME) LIKE '%hardy%' and subcat IS NULL
ORDER BY str_to_date(ACCESSSTARTS, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s'), article_no limit 0, 10
```

Notice the **subcat IS NULL** in the WHERE clause.

Comment: This still returns an empty result set

Comment: I have to use subcat ="". I set the fields to be null in mysql however. Is it because the fieldtype is varchar?

Comment: try this:

SELECT ARTICLE_NO, USERNAME, ACCESSSTARTS, ARTICLE_NAME, date_format(str_to_date(ACCESSSTARTS, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s'), '%d %m %Y' ) AS shortDate 
FROM AUCTIONS
WHERE ARTICLE_NAME LIKE '%hardy%' and (subcat IS NULL OR subcat = '')
ORDER BY str_to_date(ACCESSSTARTS, '%d.%m.%Y %k:%i:%s'), article_no limit 0, 10

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
subcat IS NULL
```

Besides that, I think you want to use:

```
lower(ARTICLE_NAME) LIKE '%hardy%'
```

because you use lowercase in the like string.

Comment: Hmm, that still gives an empty result set.

Comment: Try to remove the Like condition. If that gives still no rows, try subcat = "" (empty instead of NULL)

Comment: In the latter case you need to change the values of subcat (in the table)

Comment: subcat = "" works.., is this because the fieldtype is a varchar?

Comment: It's a varchar and the value is empty, not NULL (that's different)